# Write a program that prints in ascending order the first n natural

Tags: c

Write a program that prints in ascending order the first n natural numbers that have a property not to be divisible by any other prime number except 2, 3 and 5.

So in my head I know approximately what I need to do:

I will need one variable for example `int n = 13` that would indicate what number I want to go to.
Then I would go through the loop where I would check every number up to number 13 if it is divisible by prime number except numbers 2,3,5.

```
for(i = 1; i <=13;i++){
if(i == 2 && i == 3 && i == 5) ....
```

Im trying to fix this but idk how excatly, if someone could help?

Comment: `i` cannot be both 2 ***and*** 3!

Comment: Take a step back and break this into smaller parts. One piece you are missing here is to test if a number is divisible by another number. For example, do you know how to test if a number is divisible  by 2 in C?

Comment: I also suggest you read about how the `&&` operator works. Then look at the `||` operator and see how they are different.

Comment: solve a simpler problem first: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Answer (score -2):

So the algorithm should be similar to

```
 int i,n;
 printf("Enter the number \n");
 scanf("%d",&n);
 for( i=1; i<=n ;i++){ /* Running a loop for first n numbers */
    if(n%2==0 && n%3==0 && n%5==0){
          printf("%d",n); /* Modulus operator returns the remainder so if the number is divisible by 2 , 3 and 5 it should return 0 , if it is divisible and not a 0 if it isn't */
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why is this answer in javascript?

Comment: Well it can be in any language, and I am a fan of javascript so why not ?, do you prefer another lanuage ?

Comment: The question is asking about C. If you're going to use pseudocode or some other language to show the algorithm you should make that clear in your answer.

Comment: Okay now it should be fine , I guess

Comment: It's the wrong answer, please read the question more carefully. You are printing numbers that are not divisible by 2, 3, 5.

Comment: I think this is still wrong. The question says "not to be divisible by any other prime number except 2, 3 and 5", which to me means that e.g. 2*3*5*7 = 210 should *not* be printed out, but your algorithm would do that.